# TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

Tags: excel, reactjs

I am trying to read Excel data file using following function:

```
handleFiles = (f, evt) => {

    var name = f.name;
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = evt => {

      /* Parse data */
      const bstr = evt.target.result;

      const wb = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: "binary" });
      console.log("data>>>", wb);
      /* Get first worksheet */
      const wsname = wb.SheetNames[0];
      const ws = wb.Sheets[wsname];
      /* Convert array of arrays */
      const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_csv(ws, { header: 1 });
      /* Update state */
      console.log("Data>>>", data);
    };

    reader.readAsBinaryString(evt.target.files[0]);
  };
```

And the fuction is called using a button call :

```
  <Button onClick={this.handleFiles}>UPLOAD</Button>
```

When calling the function the error is displayed as "TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined". Is there any solutions for make this error correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your Code

```
 <Button onClick={this.handleFiles}>UPLOAD</Button>
```

Replace by this code

```
<Button onClick={(e)=>this.handleFiles(e)}>UPLOAD</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have not explicitly passed arguments to the event handler i.e used as

`<Button onClick={this.handleFiles}>UPLOAD</Button>`,

the first argument passed to event handler `handleFiles` is the event object.

So in above code

```
handleFiles = (f, evt) => {...}
```

Actual event object is `f`.

Since you have not explicitly passed second `evt` argument to event handler `handleFiles`. So it is `undefined` and trying to access property `target` of `undefined` gives the error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

So to solve this, you can explicitly pass the arguments.

```
<Button onClick={(evt) => this.handleFiles('someArgument', evt)}>UPLOAD</Button>
```